# Categorizing the columns of one row in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database table with records like the picture:

So each record contains columns related to points of the project lifecycle. I need to categorize those columns in order to know how many columns are 'completed' or 'In Progress' or 'Not started'
I want the output to be organized in a simple table.

[image: Example of record Image]

Comment: [How to ask....](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  It is very hard to get info out of a picture which is blurred for more than 40%....

Comment: It is just to give an extra explanation. The point is when I have multiple cols in one row how can I categorize them based on the text written in them?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question, and make a [mre] with sample input, and desired output (in TEXT) ?

Comment: I was struggling with forming the table using text format actually haha, but sure I will. Even though the problem is resolved now, but It may help someone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS projects;
CREATE TABLE projects(id int primary key, column1 varchar(20),column2 varchar(20),column3 varchar(20));

INSERT INTO projects VALUES( 1,'Completed','Not Started','Completed');
INSERT INTO projects VALUES( 2,'Completed','Not Started','Completed');
INSERT INTO projects VALUES( 3,'Completed','Not Started','In Progress');


select 
   id, 
   count(CASE WHEN left(c,9)='Completed' THEN 1 END) as 'Competed',
   count(CASE WHEN left(c,11)='In Progress' THEN 1 END) as 'In Progress',
   count(CASE WHEN left(c,11)='Not Started' THEN 1 END) as 'Not Started'
from (
   SELECT id,Column1 as C from  projects
   union all
   SELECT id,Column2 from  projects
   union all 
   SELECT id,Column3 from  projects
   ) x
group by id;
```

output:

```
id          Competed    In Progress Not Started
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           0           1
2           2           0           1
3           1           1           1
```

[DBFIDDLE-MSSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf014e8e8209338c8e16622f764dbb25)

[DBFIDDLE-MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=edd4801d22e5df604a2b2a2f1ff96f43)

Comment: oops, i typed 'Competed' in stead of 'Completed'... 

Comment: That is exactly the query I desired. Thank you !